# JQuery autocomplete combobox line items breaking in IE (all versions) this will take a looksie

Tags: jquery, html, combobox

I have an autocomplete combo-box inside a div which opens up into a dialog box. In IE the line items are crammed together and text is not a all visible. You can get the source code, such as I have, directly from JQuery and experience the error such as I have.

For an explanation of use (in case you think it is necessary): This is a pop-up holding a combobox for email addresses. I'm after the dialog loads I use BindUsers to retrieve the list and use the success to build. I've experienced another issue here where I would add a null or "Enter an email" value and when I append the rest of the options the element I previously added is overwritten.

Also the alert which should fire, never fires....

If this isn't enough, you might shoot some ducks and not down vote every post you don't understand. I'm looking for a relatively quick response... Thanks.
Link to src:
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

```js
 function BindUsers(){
            $.ajax({ url: '<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Chat_getCurrentTickets.aspx")%>',
                data: { fetch: "GetUserList"}, 
                async: false,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: "json",
                success: onBindUserSuccess, 
                error: function(){(alert('Error getting list of recipients'))}});      
        }

        function onBindUserSuccess(data){           
            
            //opt.value = '-1';
            //opt.text = 'Enter an email';
            //$('#combobox').append(opt);
            //$('#combobox').selectedIndex = -1;

            for(var i=0;i< data.length;i++){
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                if(data[i].OperatorName.trim() != ''){
                    opt.value = data[i].Email;
                    opt.text = data[i].OperatorName;
                    $('#combobox').append(opt);
                }
            }
        }

        (function( $ ) {
            $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
                _create: function() {
                    this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
                      .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
                      .insertAfter( this.element );
 
                    this.element.hide();
                    this._createAutocomplete();
                    this._createShowAllButton();
                },
 
                _createAutocomplete: function() {
                    var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
                      value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
 
                    this.input = $( "<input>" )
                      .appendTo( this.wrapper )
                      .val( value )
                      .attr( "title", "" )
                      .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
                      .autocomplete({
                          delay: 0,
                          minLength: 0,
                          source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
                      })
                      .tooltip({
                          tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
                      });
 
                    this._on( this.input, {
                        autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
                            ui.item.option.selected = true;
                            this._trigger( "select", event, {
                                item: ui.item.option
                            });
                        },
 
                        autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
                    });
                },
 
                _createShowAllButton: function() {
                    var input = this.input,
                      wasOpen = false;
 
                    $( "<a>" )
                      .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
                      .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
                      .tooltip()
                      .appendTo( this.wrapper )
                      .button({
                          icons: {
                              primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                          },
                          text: false
                      })
                      .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
                      .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
                      .mousedown(function() {
                          wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
                      })
                      .click(function() {
                          input.focus();
 
                          // Close if already visible
                          if ( wasOpen ) {
                              return;
                          }
 
                          // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                          input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                      });
                },
 
                _source: function( request, response ) {
                    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
                    response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                        var text = $( this ).text();
                        if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                            return {
                                label: text,
                                value: text,
                                option: this
                            };
                    }) );
                },
 
                
 
                _destroy: function() {
                    this.wrapper.remove();
                    this.element.show();
                }
            });
        })( jQuery );

        //$( ".combobox" ).autocomplete({
        //    appendTo: "#dialog"
        //});
 
        $(function() {
            $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
            $("#combobox").change(function() {
                alert($(this).val());  //To fetch the value                 
            });
            $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
                $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
            });
        });
```

```html
<div id="dialog" title="Help Desk Email" style="display:none;" class="ui-front">                  
                    <div style="width:100%;"> 
                        <div>
                            <div style="width:100%;display:inline-block">
                                <input type="button" id="btnSend" value="Send" onclick="btnSendClickEvent()" style="margin:25px 25px 5px 5px" />
                                <label title="Select a recipient" id="RadCBTo" style="height:25px;margin-right:36px">To: </label>                            
                                <select id="combobox" >
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">Insert or select and email address</option>
                                </select>            
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label id="label2" style="height:20px;width:300px; margin:25px 5px 5px 80px">Subject: </label>
                                <input type="text" id="txtSubject" style="height:20px;width:550px;" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="tbTo" />                            
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <textarea id="tdBody" aria-multiline="true" style="margin:25px 5px 5px 138px; width:inherit;" cols="90" rows="25"></textarea> 
                                <label id="label1" style="background-color:red;"></label>  
                                <input type="hidden" id="resolve"/>                            
                            </div>               
                        </div>                                                  
                    </div>              
                </div>
```

This is what I get in chrome and not what I get in IE... That is the problem.[image]

[image: This is what I get in IE, not what I want]

I have an autocomplete combo-box inside a div which opens up into a dialog box. In IE the line items are crammed together and text is not a all visible. You can get the source code, such as I have, directly from JQuery and experience the error such as I have.

For an explanation of use (in case you think it is necessary): This is a pop-up holding a combobox for email addresses. I'm after the dialog loads I use BindUsers to retrieve the list and use the success to build. I've experienced another issue here where I would add a null or "Enter an email" value and when I append the rest of the options the element I previously added is overwritten.

Also the alert which should fire, never fires....

Comment: I'd recommend changing the title, the "Not for trolls" is irrelevant and unnecessary to the question.

Comment: Yeah, I just got a little flustered when someone was like "I don't understand your problem", like really?

Comment: So far what I'm seeing is that IE is assigning the line-items different id's and class's from what chrome is.

Comment: It turns out that it has something to do with my 
 function onBindUserSuccess(data);and how it is appending the elements.

Answer (score 0):

This was ultimately what I needed:

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Good documentation:
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/auto-complete-source

In the end I had to override the response method inside the _createAutocomplete to handle assigning my response data to the option. Worked like a charm. I hope this helps someone. Good luck :)

```
    (function($) {
        $.widget("custom.combobox", {
            _create: function() {
                this.wrapper = $("<span>")
                .addClass("custom-combobox")
                .insertAfter(this.element);

                this.element.hide();
                this._createAutocomplete();
                this._createShowAllButton();
            },

            _createAutocomplete: function() {
                var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

                this.input = $("<input>")
                .appendTo(this.wrapper)
                .val(value)
                .attr("title", "")
                .attr("name", "comboboxinput")
                .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")                    
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,

                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Chat_getCurrentTickets.aspx")%>',
                            dataType: "JSON",
                            async: false,
                            type: 'GET',
                            data: { fetch: "GetUserList"},                                
                            success: function(data) {    
                                var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                                response(                                        
                                    $.map( data, function(item){                                           
                                        if (!request.term || matcher.test(item.OperatorName)){ 
                                            if(item.OperatorName.length >5){
                                                return{
                                                    label: item.OperatorName,
                                                    value: item.Email,
                                                    option: this
                                                }   
                                            }        
                                        }                                                                 
                                }));
                            },
                            error: function(){(alert('Error getting list of recipients'))}   
                        });
                    }                        
                })
                .tooltip({
                    tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
                });

                this._on(this.input, {
                    autocompleteselect: function(event, ui) {
                        ui.item.option.selected = true;
                        this._trigger("select", event, {
                            item: ui.item.option
                        });
                    },

                    autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
                });
            },

            _createShowAllButton: function() {
                var input = this.input,
                wasOpen = false;

                $("<a>")
                .attr("tabIndex", -1)
                .attr("title", "Show All Items")
                .tooltip()
                .appendTo(this.wrapper)
                .button({
                    icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                    },
                    text: false
                })
                .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
                .mousedown(function() {
                    wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
                })
                .click(function() {
                    input.focus();

                    // Close if already visible
                    if (wasOpen) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                    input.autocomplete("search", "");
                });
            },              

            _removeIfInvalid: function(event, ui) {

                // Selected an item, nothing to do
                if (ui.item) {
                    return;
                }

                // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
                var value = this.input.val(),
                valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
                valid = false;
                this.element.children("option").each(function() {
                    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
                        this.selected = valid = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                // Found a match, nothing to do
                if (valid) {
                    return;
                }

                // Remove invalid value
                this.input.val("")
                .attr("title", value + " didn't match any item")
                .tooltip("open");
                this.element.val("");
                this._delay(function() {
                    this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
                }, 2500);
                this.input.autocomplete("instance").term = "";
            },

            _destroy: function() {
                this.wrapper.remove();
                this.element.show();
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: just like some SO users to down vote without a comment